# Why doesn't the image formation take place on the mirror in the case of plane mirrors? Why does it take place behind the mirror? Please help me out

Tags: optics, reflection

People say that the image forms behind the mirror in the case of plane mirrors. But I feel that they must take place on the mirror. I cannot come into terms with this explanation.

Comment: It's a _virtual_ image. It is not physically forming behind the mirror, but it appears as though it does. Hence the term _virtual._ But you are correct in that the physical light rays are in the front of the mirror and come from the mirror.

Comment: Right, to the viewer with normal depth perception it appears as if the image is originating in a space that's "behind" the mirror - thus the metaphor. In case you don't have depth perception - it's hard to explain, but it literally appears as if the space extends *inside* the mirror, like you could walk through it (ass opposed to, say, a photo, which appears flat).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When terming Image formation , People always tend to group the images into two categories virtual(cannot be projected on a screen) and real(can be projected on a screen).

In terms of plane mirror the light is getting reflected and it does not go "through" the mirror to be projected on a screen and hence its image is said to be virtual , that virtual image is what we see in the mirror and is the case of convex mirrors as well.

For the physical aspect , yes there are light rays going through the process of reflection and hitting our eye but that is not in terms with our definition of an image

Answer (score -2):

If you look at a mirror, some people see the picture on the mirror, some behind. if your ey adjusts to the frame of the mirror you see the picture on the mirror. but if you use a window as mirror  maybe when its dark outside you will see the picture outside in about the distance you or a lamp are inside. Since the picture is not real you may see it at the distance your ey adjusts to.